# Send Excel file from sharepoint to an email - file format or extension not valid

Tags: excel, outlook, power-automate

I'm following an instruction from here https://www.powertechtips.com/attach-files-to-email-power-automate/ to send a copy of an excel workbook stored in a SharePoint location via email.

I'm running into an error when it is received that it cannot be opened  'because the file format or file extension is not valid'
The file extension is .xlsx in both sharepoint and in the attachment.
One part that I can see has changed, using the dynamic content to select the changes to an expression using base64 which I'm not very familiar with. Could this be the potential issue? I can't seem to prevent it from occurring so if this is a likely issue I'm interested in some help to get this attachment working well.

I only have two steps, get file content (sharepoint) and Send an email V2 (Outlook 365)

I've tried get file content followed by email.
I've also tried assembling this into an array followed by a csv as I'd done this for backing up a list before. Unfortunately this doesn't work the same as the prior attempt.
[Flow picure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fdIX.png)

Comment: There's probably a better way to get the file to sharepoint via power automate than emailing it as an attachment.

Comment: Perhaps share a snip or two of your flow.

Comment: @SamNseir added a picture

Comment: @pgSystemTester The other way around, the file is on SharePoint and I want to email it to someone

Comment: Can you click on the `...` on the send email action, and select `Peek code`. Then share what it says. Interested in seeing the attachments part.

Comment: I've SOLVED this:
I used the Excel 365 module to get all table rows, ten used the 'data operation' action 'Create CSV table' with the results
I could then attach the output of that table as [name variable].csv

Answer (score 0):

I've SOLVED this: I used the Excel 365 module to get all table rows, ten used the 'data operation' action 'Create CSV table' with the results I could then attach the output of that table as [name variable].csv

So there is some functionality lost (coloured formatting etc) but the info is backed up